# How to get user name on Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework. How to get user name of user when they are chatting with Microsoft Bot on Microsoft Teams.I am using bot builder and node.js

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get the name of the person using:

```
session.message.address.user.name
```

Though you may have to check that, as different channel exposes different kind of data to the framework. Also you can have a look in the `channelData` field as well. It contains data specific to the channel. You can find channel data using:

```
session.message.source
```